# Swiftype rails, post_url undefined method when running worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, swiftype

I'm trying to implement [Swiftype](https://swiftype.com) on Rails 3.2.5. However, when adding a category, and running `rake jobs:work`, I get the following error message:

> CreateSwiftypeDocumentJob failed with NoMethodError: undefined method
>   `post_url' for #

In the `CreateSwiftypeDocumentJob` model I have :

```
post = ProposalCategory.find(proposal_category_id) 
url = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.post_url(post)
```

If somebody could please help with this, that'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`post_url` should only be used if you actually have a route for the Post resource.

What is in your `routes.rb` file? Presumably something like:

```
resources :proposal_categories
```

In that case, you would need to use a route like `proposal_category_url`.